# When a client receives a transaction id, what does that mean?

Tags: transactions, node, return

When a client submits a transaction to a node it receives a return code including, if successful, a transaction id.

What does receipt of this transaction id indicate? Does it indicate simply that the transaction was pre-validated by the node and queued for forwarding to peer nodes? Or does it indicate something more or less?